# Teach LLM to generate code using a specific library

Tags: llm

I am curious to know after seeing good code examples generated by Github copilot.

I am wondering if I can create an Agent which basically takes commands as plain English and generates code based on one particular framework.

Lets say I have a basic web library like jQuery
or even simpler one library which only has two functions `makeCircle(radius)` and `makeRectangle(a,b)`

Now I want to build a system, which if I command it like this - "Create a big rectangle of size 8 X 10 and fit as many 2 radius circles keeping a gap of 1 unit between the circles as well as the rectangle"

and it does the calculation and generates code or even pseudo code like -

```
makeRectangle(8X10);
for (int i=0;.....
checkOverlap()
........
```

and so on

Is it possible to achieve this on a particular library? without a lot of training data?